# Setuptools doesn't find a package that is installed

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools, python-3.10

I am trying to install a package "editable" for developing. I have already installed all dependencies into my virtualenv, but the installation of the package is failing:

```
$ . ./venv/bin/activate
$ pip install -e ../../grader_service
Obtaining file:///Users/jason/src/Grader-Service/grader_service
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build editable ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build editable did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
...
        File "/private/var/folders/0w/khw84_v56_n_h398ssh0b6l00000gn/T/pip-build-env-50lklzpz/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
        File "/Users/jason/src/Grader-Service/grader_service/grader_service/main.py", line 18, in <module>
          import tornado
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tornado'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

It cannot find `tornado` although it is clearly installed:

```
$ which python
/Users/jason/src/Grader-Service/examples/dev_environment/venv/bin/python
$ python -c "import tornado"
```

I am using Python 3.10.7 from Homebrew on macOS Ventura 13.0.1 (M1). I think setuptools is running python here in a subprocess, and picking up the wrong interpreter, so it can't find the dependency from the virtualenv. Is there any way to fix this?

I've added some debugging prints to my code, and it seems setuptools is importing my main module with a wrong PYTHONPATH (the venv is not included, but some PEP517 stuff is):

```
sys.executable: /Users/jason/src/Grader-Service/examples/dev_environment/venv/bin/python
sys.argv: ['setup.py', 'egg_info']
sys.path: ['/Users/jason/src/Grader-Service/grader_service', '/Users/jason/src/Grader-Service/examples/dev_environment/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process', '/private/var/folders/0w/khw84_v56_n_h398ssh0b6l00000gn/T/pip-build-env-ab7ntspc/site', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python310.zip', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/private/var/folders/0w/khw84_v56_n_h398ssh0b6l00000gn/T/pip-build-env-ab7ntspc/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/private/var/folders/0w/khw84_v56_n_h398ssh0b6l00000gn/T/pip-build-env-ab7ntspc/normal/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
```

Comment: Have you tried `pip cache purge` to clear pip's cache?

Comment: That didn't help, but adding '--no-use-pep517' to the pip command line did. It works now but I wonder what is going on.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue on two different M1 macbooks.  The '--no-use-pep517' option worked.